# Mongodb restore problems

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb, running on an Ubuntu 12.04 box, decided to dump core because it opened too many files (applause).  After running `mongod --repair` as root as http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/ alluded to (but didn't specify), I now find that mongo has apparently whacked out its own file permissions somehow - every time I try to start I get

```
Mon Apr  1 15:10:08 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log", nojournal: "true" }
Mon Apr  1 15:10:09 [initandlisten] couldn't open /var/lib/mongod/cerebro_test_import_ayp_part2.ns errno:1 Operation not permitted
Mon Apr  1 15:10:09 [initandlisten] error couldn't open file /var/lib/mongodb/cerebro_test_import_ayp_part2.ns terminating
```

"Operation not permitted"?  Really?  Even after

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mongodb
```

?  I'm a couple of millimeters away from just blowing this whole database away and chalking it up as yet another reason Mongo sucks.  What can I do to get mongo happy again so I don't have to do that?  What haven't I tried?  What gives?

Comment: I often get permissions issues when trying to have programs use /var/lib/x, a simple work around is to run the software as root or just use another directory.  If you choose to use another directory, you can just move the files in /var/lib/mongodb to the directory of your choice and set that as your dbpath.  Could you have started your mongod instance as root when you first ran it?  You should not have to run mongod --repair as root, so it seems that this might be related...

Comment: Yeah, I guess maybe I should have run repair as the mongodb user.  Documentation didn't have anything to say about that unfortunately...

Comment: Were you able to run mongod with that path as root or move the files successfully?  Just want to make sure you are not still running into issues.  Also see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/ulimit/ for more info on raising the limits for the maximum number of files open.

Comment: It's running as root at the moment, but I view that as a temporary measure...

Answer (score 9):

Did you try
`sudo chown -Rh mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongod*`?

This has all the hallmarks of a Linux permissions problem, chmod'ding 777 is always a bad idea.

Comment: I thought about that, but didn't try it - I couldn't come up with a reason that files chmod'ed 777 would suddenly become writable if I chown'ed them.  Care to provide one?  ;-)